# F# System.TypeLoadException : The generic type 'System.Tuple`3' was used with an invalid instantiation in assembly

Tags: .net, f#

I have a very strange bug in `Debug` mode in an F# assembly, and this bug disappears in `Release` mode. I have tried .NET 4.0, 4.5, 4.6, I also tried on a machine that doesn't have VS2015 and .NET 4.6. I also tried F# 3.1 and 4.0.

> System.TypeLoadException : The generic type 'System.Tuple`3' was used
>   with an invalid instantiation in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

or (the difference is only in Tuple'2 or '3)

> System.TypeLoadException : The generic type 'System.Tuple`2' was used
>   with an invalid instantiation in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I develop in release mode with a special flag `Prerelease` for conditional compilation - to be able to run meaningful performance benchmarks in `Release` on every change (the flag is set in both Debug and Release). Therefore, I have no place where `#if DEBUG...` is used, and I have double-checked this.

What this error means? Do you have any idea where to look for the fix? I have no idea and still cannot chase the place where it is actually thrown. The stack trace is not useful as it shows the top calling method.

In my build output, I have a warning that I have never seen before, but it appears in both `Debug` and `Release` and is probably irrelevant.

> FSC: warning FS3186: An error occurred while reading the F# metadata
>   node at position 3223 in table 'itypars' of assembly
>   'Spreads.Collections, Version=0.0.31.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The node had no matching declaration. Please
>   report this warning. You may need to recompile the F# assembly you are
>   using.

Comment: My guess based on the last warning is that something goes wrong because you have another assembly that is built using a different version of the F# compiler (and contains some metadata about the compiled F# code that the new compiler you are using does not understand for some reason). I suppose this should not be happening (new F# should be able to use assemblies compiled by old F#), but perhaps it's some kind of bug...

Comment: So I would probably try recompiling the assembly `Spreads.Collection` (or assemblies it depends on) and see what happens?

Comment: Oh, I did recompile it many times and deleted `bin` manually. I used the dll only (it has not dependencies other than .NET) compiled with 3.1 and tried it on a machine that knows nothing about F# 4.0 and .NET 4.6 and made sure that the solution there also targets F# 3.1 from NuGet... Hunting it now for yet another hour.

Comment: Huh, then I'm out of ideas!

Comment: When I check the box `Optimize code` in the Debug mode, it works, but I guess it effectively gives me the Release mode.

Comment: I have found the root cause - inlining in Debug mode creates some weird tuples as temporal storage, and uses `ref` in tuples constructor and then tries to modify those tuple's `ref` items. There are no those tuples in Release mode, inlining looks like true one. My solution is to manually inline the code. I believe this is a bug in F# compiler, will try to reproduce it in an isolated example some day.

Comment: Could be related to this https://twitter.com/bergius/status/625276837799796737 ?

Comment: This is not related to VS2015 or .NET 4.6, see my answer to the question with a minimum repro. I have submitted an issue on Github/MSFT/F#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is minimal example that reproduces the issue.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Runtime.InteropServices


module Test =

  type MyType<'A,'B,'C>() =
    let mutable counter = 0
    member this.Counter with get() = counter and set(v) = counter <- v
    member inline this.TryDoWorkChecked(next:KeyValuePair<'A,'B>, [<Out>] value: byref<'C>) : bool =
      let before = this.Counter
      let res = this.TryDoWork(next, &value)
      if before <> this.Counter then raise (InvalidOperationException("Must not change counter during work"))
      else res
    abstract TryDoWork: next:KeyValuePair<'A,'B> * [<Out>] value: byref<'C> -> bool
    override this.TryDoWork(next:KeyValuePair<'A,'B>, [<Out>] value: byref<'C>) : bool =
      value <- Unchecked.defaultof<'C>
      if counter > 10 then true else false

    member this.DoWork(next:KeyValuePair<'A,'B>) =
      let mutable value = Unchecked.defaultof<'C>
      while not (this.TryDoWorkChecked(next, &value)) do
        counter <- counter + 1


open Test

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let myType = MyType<int,int,int>()
    let next = Unchecked.defaultof<KeyValuePair<int,int>>
    myType.DoWork(next)
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

In Debug mode, ILSpy shows this:

```
// Program.Test.MyType<A, B, C>
public unsafe void DoWork(KeyValuePair<A, B> next)
{
    C value = default(C);
    while (true)
    {
        Tuple<KeyValuePair<A, B>, C*> tuple = new Tuple<KeyValuePair<A, B>, C*>(next, ref value);
        KeyValuePair<A, B> item = tuple.Item1;
        C* item2 = tuple.Item2;
        int num = this.Counter;
        bool flag = this.TryDoWork(item, item2);
        if ((num == this.Counter) ? flag : Operators.Raise<bool>(new InvalidOperationException("Must not change counter during work")))
        {
            break;
        }
        this.counter++;
    }
}
```

And this is ILSpy output in Release mode:

```
// Program.Test.MyType<A, B, C>
public void DoWork(KeyValuePair<A, B> next)
{
    C value = default(C);
    while (true)
    {
        int num = this.counter;
        bool flag = this.TryDoWork(next, out value);
        if (num != this.counter)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            return;
        }
        this.counter++;
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Must not change counter during work");
}
```

I believe this is a bug in F# compiler.